# Pagination in Angular 4 showing all elements in a single page

Tags: angular, typescript, pagination, angular-cli

I'm trying to apply pagination in Angular 4 with [this tutorial](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/08/23/angular-2-pagination-example-with-logic-like-google) but I have an error when I apply pagination with an array of length = 20 or length =10 or length=40, I have only one page in pagination.

For example when I add an array of length = 40, I add this pagination:

[image]

One page in pagination and all elements of the array in a single page.

Code service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
        import * as _ from 'underscore';

        @Injectable()
        export class PagerService {

          constructor() { }

          getPager(totalItems: number , currentPage: number = 1, pageSize: number =10) {
                // calculate total pages
                let totalPages = Math.ceil(totalItems / pageSize);
                let startPage: number, endPage: number;
                if (totalPages <= 10) {
                    // less than 10 total pages so show all
                    startPage = 1;
                    endPage = totalPages;
                } else {
                    // more than 10 total pages so calculate start and end pages
                    if (currentPage <= 6) {
                        startPage = 1;
                        endPage = 10;
                    } else if (currentPage + 4 >= totalPages) {
                        startPage = totalPages - 9;
                        endPage = totalPages;
                    } else {
                        startPage = currentPage - 5;
                        endPage = currentPage + 4;
                    }
                }
         
                // calculate start and end item indexes
                let startIndex = (currentPage - 1) * pageSize;
                let endIndex = Math.min(startIndex + pageSize - 1, totalItems - 1);

                // create an array of pages to ng-repeat in the pager control
                let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);
                // return object with all pager properties required by the view
                return {
                    totalItems: totalItems,
                    currentPage: currentPage,
                    pageSize: pageSize,
                    totalPages: totalPages,
                    startPage: startPage,
                    endPage: endPage,
                    startIndex: startIndex,
                    endIndex: endIndex,
                    pages: pages
                };
            }
        }
```

Code component:

```
sz= ['Saab', 'Volvo', "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"
  , "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"
  , "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW","Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

    constructor( public pagerService:PagerService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.setPage(this.sz.length);
      });

    }

        setPage(page: number) {

          if (page < 1 || page > this.pager.totalPages) {
              return;
          }
          // get pager object from service
          this.pager = this.pagerService.getPager(this.dataBikes.length, page);

          // get current page of items
          this.pagedItems = this.sz.slice(0, this.sz.length);
      }
```

How can I add 10 items of the array per page? E.g. length of array in code component is 40, how to make 4 pages?

Answer (score 0):

You have

```
let pages = _.range(startPage, endPage + 1);
```

that's: to create the array you're using "lodash". I supouse you have not "lodash" (it's not necesarry, but you must change the way to create the array). You can replace the before code by

```
let pages:number[]=[]
for (let i=startPage;i<=endPage;i++)
    pages.push(i);
```